# Check if directory exists not working

Tags: linux, bash

I have a textfile (qrs.txt) which contains dir names (one per line) and on my server in the same directory as the script I have those folders with corresponding names from the text file.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p; do
  if [ ! -d "$p" ];
    then
        echo "ERROR $p" >> log.txt
    else
        echo "GOOD" >> log.txt
    fi
done < qrs.txt
```

qrs.txt:

```
1992300000183805
1992300001176204
1992300002145500
1992300003104507
1992300004104902
1992300005133703
1992300006117802
1992300007144501
1992300008172803
1992300009189005
1992300010146307
1992300011151700
1992300012190007
1992300013126802
1992300014111508
1992300015193908
```

When that if statement is inside the loop it always returns error which is incorrect because I can see the folders exist. When I take it out of the loop and check for just 1, it works fine... When I echo $p on the same line as error, I can see the file name its checking is indeed correct.

What am I missing here..?

**EDIT:**

Screenshot of qrs.txt in hex mode:

http://i.snag.gy/25mqJ.jpg

**RESOLVED!**

**My qrs.txt was in [dos] format originally but once converted to unix format using ":set ff=unix" the script worked like a charm!**

Comment: I created my own `qrs.txt` file and tried your code: it works for me.

Comment: Do you think it could be the version of linux I'm running..? I'm running CentOS 5.7

Comment: do your directory names contain spaces or any "funky" characters?

Comment: all numbers.. 16 digits. some with 0's at the end.

Comment: Please show us your input (`cat qrs.txt` or whatever), and show us an `ls` that reasonably confirms that those dirs exist, show us exactly how you invoke the script and show us exactly the output.  (Perhaps drop the `>>log.txt` for the purposes of debugging.)

Comment: I've added the contents of qrs.txt

Comment: Does `qrs.txt` have DOS line endings?

Comment: nope. just the number per line - no spaces.

Comment: @chepner: I was able to recreate his problem based on your comment.

Comment: @tajonny: What I mean is, are the lines terminated by a linefeed (0x10) or a carriage-return/linefeed pair (0x13 0x10)?

Comment: Yeah I thought the same thing hoping this could fix it once you mentioned DOS endings so I opened it in VI and theres nothing. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script works fine.

I copied your script to my local machine. When I put `blh blah` in the `qrs.txt` file, I got `ERROR` for each time I ran your script. I ran it four times. I changed the `blh blah` to a valid path and I received `GOOD`.

The directory `1992300000183805` for instance, may be not be a valid path. You need the fully qualified path name! For example, `/home/user/1992300000183805`.

```
ERROR blh blah
ERROR blh blah
GOOD
GOOD
```

**EDIT**

Looking at @chepner comments, I recreated your problem:

Open your qrs.txt file in `vi` or `vim`. You should see ^M at the end of your lines. To remove the ^M characters at the end of all lines in vi, use:

```
:%s/^M//g
```

This should fix your problem. If not, in `vim` type this:

`:set ff=unix`

save the file.

Re-open `qrs.txt` in `vim`, then run the regex above again, or manually delete the `^M`.

Or you can use `perl`:

`perl -pi -e "s/\r/\n/g;" <file>`

Comment: Do I need to give the full path? such as /var/somedir/.. and so on, I was simply putting the folder name in the textfile.

Comment: weird.. because when I take the if statement out of the while loop and give the same params (just the dir name; no path) it works.. :S

Comment: Why '1992300000183805' isn't a valid path. It is _relative_ path, not _absolute_, but still valid, isn't it?

Comment: He can use a relative path if he runs the script from the good place... I made it work with relative paths.

Comment: Please see my answer below as well -- relative paths only work in the right context. Same goes for the `qrs.txt` present in the script to redirect input.

Comment: Yes I am. My script is located in the same dir where all the folders are, and that's where I am running it from.

Comment: @tajonny07: Then this is a localized problem.

Comment: @tajonny07: Are you sure /all/ of the folders exist? The log.txt is appended every time.

Comment: I opened qrs.txt in vi but there are no ^M are the end of each line. :(

Comment: @tajonny07: Open the file in `vi`. Type this `:%!xxd` to enter hex mode. What do you see? Take a screenshot of your terminal window and post it somewhere or copy the contents of it and edit your question. Type `:%!xxd -r` to exit hex mode.

Comment: @tajonny07: Also, at the bottom of the vi window, does it say "qrs.txt" [dos] NL, NNNNC? (where N is the number of lines and characters in the file?

Comment: @0A0D: I've updated my post with the screenshot. and Yes it says "qrs.txt [dos] #L, ####C"

Comment: @tajonny07: Ok, that's your problem. See that 0d0a? That's a carriage return, line feed.

Comment: so :%s/^V^M//g will remove those?

Comment: @tajonny07: you may not need the ^V.. just the ^M. If that doesn't remove it (it will say pattern not found), then see my edit about putting the file in Unix mode.

Comment: Just to clarify - Will remove the carriage returns make them side by side with nothing separating them..? Because I need them on new lines so my script knows to test each one separately you know?

Comment: @tajonny07: No, it shouldn't

Comment: Your the man! Once converted to unix format it works like a charm! Thanks bud :)

Comment: @tajonny07: No problem, seen it before.. thank you for sticking with the question.

Comment: Wait, what?  A user named *@0A0D* has seen line-ending problems before?  :)

Answer (score 0):

OK so looking at your provided file it seems those are relative directory names -- as such current directory is very important when you execute the script. Do you execute the script from its own directory or  from the parent directory to all the (sub)directories shown in your example?
In other words have you tried:

```
cd <parent directory>
/path/to/yourscript.sh
```

?

Not to mention the location of qrs.txt seems to be specified relative rather than absolute path. So if there's no qrs.txt in the current directory I don't think your script would work.

Comment: +1 to compensate for downvote.  Relative paths and CWD mismatch are a very plausible explanation for the problem given the limited information the OP has posted.

Comment: Yes I am executing the script from the relative directory to all the folders.

Comment: @pilcrow: It's formulated in the context of a comment, not an answer. Answers are not meant to solicit discussion.. that's what comments are for

Comment: but qrs.txt IS in the same directory. :(

Comment: @0A0D, agreed.  I'd add, however, that uncommented downvotes don't tell the responder how to improve his or her answers.

Comment: @pilcrow: Not to encourage a discussion here, but this has been discussed plenty of times on [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152176/139168)